# Rename a column in each join MySql

Tags: php, mysql, rename

I have 2 tables, `table1` has information about the producer (name of producer and their ID) of a resturant.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `fournisseur` (
  `IdFournisseur`          int(10) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `Fournisseur_Producteur` varchar(250) default NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY  (`IdFournisseur`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

`table2` has dailymanue and the ID of thier producer(for exampe: IdMenuPlat, IdMenuEntree...).

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `menu_jours` (
  `menu_id` int(10) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `menu_j_titre` varchar(250), `menu_date_parution`,
  `menu_entree` int(10),
  `IdMenuEntree`,`menu_plat`,`IdMenuPlat`,`menu_acc1`,`IdMenuAcc1`,`menu_acc2`,`IdMenuAcc2`,`menu_sugg`,`IdMenuSugg`,`menu_sugg_acc`,`IdMenuSuggAcc`,`menu_dessert`,`IdMenuDessert` default NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY  (`menu_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

I want to recover daily menu with the name of their producer!

I used this query:

```
todaySQL = 'SELECT * FROM table2 AS t2 
            INNER JOIN  table1 AS t1_1  ON (t1_1.IdProducter= t2.IdMenuPlat) 
            INNER JOIN  table1 AS t1_2 ON (t1_2.IdProducter= t2.IdMenuEntree) 
            INNER JOIN  table1 AS t1_3 ON (t1_3.IdProducter= t2.IdMenuAcc1) 
            INNER JOIN  table1 AS t1_4 ON (t1_4.IdProducter= t2.IdMenuAcc2)
            INNER JOIN  table1 AS t1_5 ON (t1_5.IdProducter= t2.IdMenuSugg)
            INNER JOIN  table1 AS t1_6 ON (t1_6.IdProducter= t2.IdMenuSuggAcc)
            INNER JOIN  table1 AS t1_7 ON (t1_7.IdProducter= t2.IdMenuDessert)

            WHERE menu_date_parution = \''.$todayDate.'\'' ;
```

but if I use this function:

```
todayRow = mysql_fetch_row( todaySQL )
```

I have all information in array by their index which is confusing for programming I would like  to use this function:

```
todayRow = mysql_fetch_assoc( todaySQL )
```

which recover in array by the name of columns, but the problem is that I just have the infortmaion of the last producer ,not for the information of the all.

I think I should rename the column's name of producer(Fournisseur_Producteur) for each join. But how?

Answer (score 0):

If i understand well, you dont use a loop to fetch the results.

You need a for or a while:

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($todaySQL)) {
echo $row['menu_id'];
}
```